# Pegar itens de um array convertendo para UTF8

Tags: php, array, utf-8, utf8-decode

Olá! O meu problema é o seguinte:
Tenho uma lista de valores em um arquivo php externo e quando eu uso um include para chamar os valores em meu template os caractéres com acentos são substituídos por interrogações. 
Gostaria de saber se existe uma função  ou uma outra forma de pegar os valores codificando-os para UTF8.

Exemplo:

```js
$lang = array();
$lang['LANGUAGE'] = 'português';
$lang['HOME'] = 'início';
```

e dentro do template chamo assim:

```js
include 'lista.php';
echo $lang['HOME'];
```

Daí aparece inic?o

OBS: Usei o notepad++ para formata-los em UTF-8 sem bom e resolveu na maioria das palavras, no entanto em textos de dentro de botões não funcionou. Veja na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tentou salvar o arquivo com utf-8 sem bom? eu salvo assim, parei de ter problemas com acentuação a um bom tempo depois que comecei a salvar tudo com utf-8 sem bom

Comment: Sim usei o notepad++ para formata-los e deu certo na maioria das frases, no entanto, para as palavras de dentro de botões não funcionaram.

Comment: dentro dos botões? você diz, input type button? tentou utilizar isso no cabeçalho do seu arquivo <meta charset='utf-8' /> ?

Comment: Coloquei a imagem na pergunta, veja. No header do meu site o charset tá ok. o erro só ocorre com palavras puxadas do array externo do arquivo lista.php, as palavras que saõ de dentro do template funciona normalmente.

Comment: poderia mostrar o link de seu site? e tente colocar este código no include para ver se funciona <?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); include 'lista.php'; ?>

Comment: cara, achei um cara com problema muito parecido com o seu neste link http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/283085-resolvido-acentuacao-utf-8-e-iso/

Comment: Uso wordpress. Vou tentar esse código aí que vc passou pra ver.

Comment: Tente isso no link, se nao der poste os outros arquivos http://br.phptherightway.com/#php_e_utf8

Comment: Geralmente é conflito do servidor com a codificação, já resolvi isso com ANSI em vez de UTF-8 na meta tag, outra alternativa é codificar a saída exemplo: utf8_encode($saida);

Comment: Felipe já tentei essas duas opções aí que vc mencionou, também não deu. Estou tentando localmente com o easy php e você disse que pode ser conflito de servidor, será que é por isso que não está dando certo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido. Como eu tinha dito anteriormente, usei o notepad++ para formata-los em UTF-8 sem bom e resolveu na maioria das palavras, menos em palavras dentro de botões.

Voltei e formatei novamente no notepad++, porem dessa vez em UTF-8 e deu certo. O porque eu não sei, mas o importante é que resolvi.

Agradeço a todos que me deram força e optaram nesse processo complicado que tira a paz de muita gente. Valeu galera!